# How to identify the inequality involved in an arithmetic expression specified by a prolog query?

Tags: prolog, logic, constraint-programming

I am working on prolog and faced this scenario -
In my query, I pass something like this:

```
?- query( 2*X + 3*Y >= 3*Z )
```

Now, what I would like to do is have the prolog program capture the inequality expression so that I can have the above inequality in variables like below:

variable '`Lhs`' will have `2*X + 3*Y`
variable '`Rhs`' will have `3*Z`
Now I want the inequality involved to be also assigned somewhere (in a variable called Opr??), so that saying something like Lhs Opr Rhs would mean exactly like saying "`2*X + 3*Y >= 3*Z`"..

This is a general form of the scenario that I am working on. I somehow want the "inequality" involved to be identified, so that I can use it later in my code.

I am working on Eclipse-CLP with IC library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use univ to disassemble your inequaliy:

```
Eq =.. [Op,Lhs,Rhs],
```

This works in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with any prolog system, using the [univ/2](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/termmanip/EDD-2.html) operator:

```
parse_ops(Expr, Lhs, Rhs, Op):-
  Expr =.. [Op, Lhs, Rhs].

?- parse_ops(2*X + 3*Y >= 3*Z, Lhs, Rhs, Op).
Lhs = 2*X+3*Y,
Rhs = 3*Z,
Op = (>=).
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to simply do:

```
parse_query(LHS >= RHS, LHS, RHS).

?- parse_query(2*X + 3*Y >= 3*Z, LHS, RHS).
LHS=2*X + 3*Y 
RHS=3*Z
```

What you need to be concerned here with is order of operations the Parser uses when reading your query.  Take a look at [the op/3 operator for eclipse-clp](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/syntax/op-3.html) and [the op/3 operator doc for swi-prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=op/3).  Notice the precedence number for inequalities are higher than operators.  This means that when the query (2*X +3*Y >=3*Z) is parsed, the >= operator becomes the functor.  Try to use the display predicate to make this clear.

```
?- display(2*X + 3*Y >= 3*Z).
>=(+(*(2,X), *(3,Y)), *(3,Z))
```